# Cython: unsigned int indices for numpy arrays gives different result

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I converted to cython a python function by just adding some types and compiling it.
I was getting small numerical differences between the results of the python and cython functions.
After some work I found that the differences came from accessing a numpy array using unsigned int instead of int.

I was using unsigned int indices to speed up access according to: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#tuning-indexing-further

anyway I thought it was harmless to use unsigned ints.

See this code:

```
cpdef function(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, max_loc):
    cdef unsigned int x, y   
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    x2, y2 = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    print response[y,x], type(response[y,x]), response.dtype
    print response[y2,x2], type(response[y2,x2]), response.dtype   
    print 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))
    print 2*(response[y2,x2] - min(response[y2,x2-1], response[y2,x2+1]))
```

prints:

```
0.959878861904 <type 'float'> float32
0.959879 <type 'numpy.float32'> float32
1.04306024313
1.04306030273
```

Why does this happen?!!! is it a bug?

Ok, as requested here is a SSCCE with the same types and values that I used in my original function

```
cpdef function():
    cdef unsigned int x, y  
    max_loc2 = np.asarray([ 15., 25.], dtype=float) 
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response2 = np.zeros((49,49), dtype=np.float32)    
    x, y = int(max_loc2[0]), int(max_loc2[1])
    x2, y2 = int(max_loc2[0]), int(max_loc2[1])

    response2[y,x] = 0.959878861904  
    response2[y,x-1] = 0.438348740339
    response2[y,x+1] = 0.753262758255  


    print response2[y,x], type(response2[y,x]), response2.dtype
    print response2[y2,x2], type(response2[y2,x2]), response2.dtype
    print 2*(response2[y,x] - min(response2[y,x-1], response2[y,x+1]))
    print 2*(response2[y2,x2] - min(response2[y2,x2-1], response2[y2,x2+1]))
```

prints

```
0.959878861904 <type 'float'> float32
0.959879 <type 'numpy.float32'> float32
1.04306024313
1.04306030273
```

I use python 2.7.3 cython 0.18 and msvc9 express

Comment: If you really want to compare `unsigned int` vs. `signed int`, instead of `unsigned int` vs. `PyObject`-or-whatever-else-Cython-chooses, you need to `cdef int x2, y2`.

Comment: More importantly: Can you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem, and the exact versions you're using. Because every version I have access to, using JoshAdel's sample values, I always get the same results for int, unsigned int, and unspecified (except for the expected print precision differences in relevant cases).

Comment: you are right with this. If I declare cdef int x2, y2 I don't get this  difference, so indeed it's cdef int or unsigned int vs PyObject-or-whatever-else-Cython-chooses

Comment: Still, it's an index, it shouldn't produce different outputs. I'm working on the SSCCE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified the example in the question to make it simpler to read the generated C source for the module. I'm only interested in seeing the logic that creates Python `float` objects instead of getting `np.float32` objects from the `response` array.

I'm using `pyximport` to compile the extension module. It saves the generated C file in a subdirectory of `~/.pyxbld` (probably `%userprofile%\.pyxbld` on Windows).

```
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs': [np.get_include()]})

open('_tmp.pyx', 'w').write('''
cimport numpy as np
cpdef function(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, max_loc):
    cdef unsigned int p_one, q_one
    p_one = int(max_loc[0])
    q_one = int(max_loc[1])
    p_two = int(max_loc[0])
    q_two = int(max_loc[1])
    r_one = response[q_one, p_one]
    r_two = response[q_two, p_two]
''')

import _tmp
assert(hasattr(_tmp, 'function'))
```

Here's the generated C code for the section of interest (a bit reformatted to make it easier to read). It turns out that when you use C `unsigned int` index variables, the generated code grabs the data directly from the array buffer and calls `PyFloat_FromDouble`, which coerces it to `double`. On the other hand, when you use Python `int` index variables, it takes the generic approach. It forms a tuple and calls `PyObject_GetItem`. This way allows the `ndarray` to correctly honor the `np.float32` dtype.

```
#define __Pyx_BufPtrStrided2d(type, buf, i0, s0, i1, s1) \
    (type)((char*)buf + i0 * s0 + i1 * s1)

  /* "_tmp.pyx":9
 *     p_two = int(max_loc[0])
 *     q_two = int(max_loc[1])
 *     r_one = response[q_one, p_one]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     r_two = response[q_two, p_two]
 */
  __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_v_q_one;
  __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_v_p_one;
  __pyx_t_5 = -1;

  if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 >= (size_t)__pyx_bshape_0_response))
    __pyx_t_5 = 0;
  if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 >= (size_t)__pyx_bshape_1_response))
    __pyx_t_5 = 1;

  if (unlikely(__pyx_t_5 != -1)) {
    __Pyx_RaiseBufferIndexError(__pyx_t_5);
    {
      __pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0];
      __pyx_lineno = 9;
      __pyx_clineno = __LINE__;
      goto __pyx_L1_error;
    }
  }

  __pyx_t_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble((
    *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided2d(
      __pyx_t_5numpy_float32_t *,
      __pyx_bstruct_response.buf,
      __pyx_t_3, __pyx_bstride_0_response,
      __pyx_t_4, __pyx_bstride_1_response)));

  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {
    __pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0];
    __pyx_lineno = 9;
    __pyx_clineno = __LINE__;
    goto __pyx_L1_error;
  }

  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_v_r_one = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;

  /* "_tmp.pyx":10
 *     q_two = int(max_loc[1])
 *     r_one = response[q_one, p_one]
 *     r_two = response[q_two, p_two]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 */
  __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_New(2);

  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {
    __pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0];
    __pyx_lineno = 10;
    __pyx_clineno = __LINE__;
    goto __pyx_L1_error;
  }

  __Pyx_GOTREF(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1));
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_v_q_two);
  PyTuple_SET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, 0, __pyx_v_q_two);
  __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_v_q_two);
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_v_p_two);
  PyTuple_SET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, 1, __pyx_v_p_two);
  __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_v_p_two);

  __pyx_t_2 = PyObject_GetItem(
    ((PyObject *)__pyx_v_response),
    ((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1));

  if (!__pyx_t_2) {
    __pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0];
    __pyx_lineno = 10;
    __pyx_clineno = __LINE__;
    goto __pyx_L1_error;
  }

  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1));
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_v_r_two = __pyx_t_2;
  __pyx_t_2 = 0;
```

Comment: Ok, this explains why! So I guess this is a bug in cython.

Comment: how to workaround it? casting every access to a float32 doesn't look good to me, the array is already float32

Comment: You can type `r_one` as `np.float32_t` for speedy calculation. Printing creates a Python `float`, but that's just for output.

Comment: I could do that, but in my original function I would need from r_one to r_ten. I think it makes my code less readable and much longer.

Comment: Then declare `r` as an array, e.g. `cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] r = (np.zeros(10, dtype=np.float32))`.

Comment: isn't that going back to the beginning? my response array was declared as a np.float32_t already. If I access the new r array with an unsigned int index I'll get a double again, won't I?

Comment: You didn't type the result of the subscription, so it created a `float` object. But when you used Python `int` indices, it already had a Python object; it used `PyObject_GetItem` to get the `np.float32` scalar. If you assign the result to a typed variable it won't create an object. Since you `cdef` the `ndarray` with a type and ndim, the assignment uses the buffer directly.

Comment: OK, I see how this works. However, even applying this new knowledge, I still have unresolved differences between cython and python. I can't get my original cython function to have the same exact decimals as the python function that came from. I'll post it soon as another question.

Comment: If you assign the a result to r[0] using indexing into the buffer, it just uses the float32 value since `ndarray r` is typed as a `np.float32_t`. If you *print* it, however, Cython doesn't know to create a `np.float32`  scalar object. It just knows it has a C `float` value and so calls `PyFloat_FromDouble` to make a Python object to print.

Comment: Hi @eryksun, thanks for your answers. I have posted a new question with my unresolved differences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376329/cython-function-output-slightly-different-from-python-function-output

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with this on my machine, I don't see a difference. I'm using the ipython notebook with cython magic:

```
In [1]:

%load_ext cythonmagic

In [12]:

%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef function(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, max_loc):
    cdef unsigned int x, y   
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    x2, y2 = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    #return 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1])), 2*(response[y2,x2] - min(response[y2,x2-1], response[y2,x2+1]))
    print response[y,x], type(response[y,x]), response.dtype
    print response[y2,x2], type(response[y2,x2]), response.dtype   
    print 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))
    print 2*(response[y2,x2] - min(response[y2,x2-1], response[y2,x2+1])) 

In [13]:

a = np.random.normal(size=(10,10)).astype(np.float32)
m = [3,2]
function(a,m)

0.586090564728 <type 'float'> float32
0.586091 <type 'numpy.float32'> float32
4.39655685425
4.39655685425
```

The first pair of results, the difference is just the output precision of the print statement. What version of Cython are you using? The indices are extremely unlikely to effect the answer since it is just accessing a fixed length of memory that the data attribute of the numpy array is storing.

Comment: This isn't really an answer… but it's hard to imagine how you could fit all of this into a comment (even with links to pastebin or whatever), so I'm not sure what else you could have done. And it's definitely useful info.