# cython function output slightly different from python function output

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have converted a python function into a cython equivalent by adding types to some variables. However, the cython function to produces slightly different output than the original python function.

I've learnt some of the reasons for this difference in this post 
[Cython: unsigned int indices for numpy arrays gives different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317851/cython-unsigned-int-indices-for-numpy-arrays-gives-different-result/15322215?noredirect=1#comment21726160_15322215) 
But even with what I've learnt in this post I still can't get the cython function to produce the same results as the python one.

So I have put together 4 functions illustrating what I have tried. Could someone help to unveil why I get slightly different results for each function? and how to get a cython function that returns the same exact values as function1? I make some comments bellow:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np    

def function1(response, max_loc):    
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])

    tmp1 = (response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]) / 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))
    tmp2 = (response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1])
    tmp3 = 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))

    print tmp1, tmp2, tmp3        
    return tmp1, tmp2, tmp3

cpdef function2(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] max_loc):
    cdef unsigned int x, y 
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])

    tmp1 = (response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]) / 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))        
    tmp2 = (response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1])
    tmp3 = 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))     

    print tmp1, tmp2, tmp3        
    return tmp1, tmp2, tmp3


cpdef function3(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] max_loc):     
    cdef unsigned int x, y 
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])

    cdef np.float32_t tmp1, tmp2, tmp3
    cdef np.float32_t r1 =response[y,x+1]
    cdef np.float32_t r2 =response[y,x-1]
    cdef np.float32_t r3 =response[y,x]
    cdef np.float32_t r4 =response[y,x-1]
    cdef np.float32_t r5 =response[y,x+1]    

    tmp1 = (r1 - r2) / 2*(r3 - min(r4, r5))  
    tmp2 = (r1 - r2)
    tmp3 = 2*(r3 - min(r4, r5))

    print tmp1, tmp2, tmp3        
    return tmp1, tmp2, tmp3

def function4(response, max_loc):     
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])

    tmp1 = (float(response[y,x+1]) - response[y,x-1]) / 2*(float(response[y,x]) - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))
    tmp2 = (float(response[y,x+1]) - response[y,x-1])
    tmp3 = 2*(float(response[y,x]) - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))

    print tmp1, tmp2, tmp3        
    return tmp1, tmp2, tmp3

max_loc = np.asarray([ 15., 25.], dtype=np.float64) 
response = np.zeros((49,49), dtype=np.float32)     
x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])

response[y,x] = 0.959878861904  
response[y,x-1] = 0.438348740339
response[y,x+1] = 0.753262758255  

result1 = function1(response, max_loc)
result2 = function2(response, max_loc)
result3 = function3(response, max_loc)
result4 = function4(response, max_loc)
print result1
print result2
print result3
print result4
```

and the results:

```
0.0821185777156 0.314914 1.04306030273
0.082118573023 0.314914017916 1.04306024313
0.0821185708046 0.314914017916 1.04306030273
0.082118573023 0.314914017916 1.04306024313
(0.082118577715618812, 0.31491402, 1.043060302734375)
(0.08211857302303427, 0.3149140179157257, 1.0430602431297302)
(0.08211857080459595, 0.3149140179157257, 1.043060302734375)
(0.082118573023034269, 0.31491401791572571, 1.0430602431297302)
```

**function1** represents the operations I did in my original python function. tmp1 is the result.

**function2** is my first cython version, which produces slightly different results. Apparently, if the response array is indexed with a typed variable, unsigned int or int, the result is coerced to a double (using PyFloat_FromDouble) even if the type of the array is np.float32_t. But if the array is indexed with a python int the function PyObject_GetItem is used instead and I get the np.float32_t, which is what  happens in function1. So the expressions in function1 are calculated using np.float32_t operands, whereas the expressions in function2 are calculated using doubles.
I get slightly different print out than in function1.

**function3** is my second cython attempt trying to get the same output as function1. Here I use unsigned int indices to access the array response but the results are left on np.float32_t intermediate variables that then I use in the calculation. I get slightly different result.  Apparently the print statement will use  PyFloat_FromDouble so it won't be able to print the np.float32_t.

Then I tried to change the python function to match the cython one. **function4** tries to achieve this by converting to float at least one operand in each expression so the rest of operands are coerced to python float too, which is a double in cython, and the expression is calculated with doubles, as in function2. The prints inside the function are exactly the same as function2, but the returned values are slightly different?!

Comment: The difference is about 10^-9 at most (one part in a billion). Why are you surprised different implementations would differ by that kind of magnitude? (And in what application would that cause a problem?)

Comment: print your float values by hex(), `print ", ".join([x.hex() for x in result4])`.

Comment: Function 1 uses Python `float` (IEEE double) values for `tmp1`, `tmp2`, and `tmp3`. Function 3 explicitly declares those as `np.float32_t` (IEEE single). How could they possibly return the same thing? Getting the intermediate types to match but then using completely different final types defeats the purpose.

Comment: Meanwhile, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? In almost every case, switching to `float` as early as possible instead of later will give you at least as good, if not better, results. Unless you have some specific reason to believe that `function2` is "wrong" or "worse" in terms of the actual values (which, as David Robinson pointed out, are probably not nearly accurate enough for this to even be meaningful), what's the problem?

Comment: Ok. Well, the purpose is that I develop the python functions first and when they behave as I want then I make a cython function for it. So I would like the cython function to give me the same result as the python. These small differences accumulate with other operations I do afterwards producing different benchmark results for my system

Comment: Plus, I want to know where the differences come from. Otherwise I'll keep ignoring subtle effects that can affect my calculations elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using single-precision floats, which only have 7.225 decimal digits of precision, I wouldn't expect a small variance from coercion to double to matter much.

To clarify your description of `function2`, if you index with an object, Cython uses`PyObject_GetItem` to get an `np.float32` scalar object (not an `np.float32_t`, which is just a typedef for a C `float`). If you instead index directly into the buffer, and Cython needs an object, it calls `PyFloat_FromDouble`. It needs objects to assign `tmp1`, `tmp2`, and `tmp3`, since they aren't typed.

In `function3`, on the other hand, you typed the `tmp` variables, but it still needs to create `float` objects to print and return the results. If you instead use a NumPy `ndarray` (see below), you won't have that problem:

In `function1`, by the way, you promote the result to `np.float64` when you divide by 2. For example:

```
>>> type(np.float32(1) / 2)
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

vs.

```
>>> type(np.float32(1) / np.float32(2))
<type 'numpy.float32'>
```

Even if you ensure that all operations are `float32` in both the `def` and `cpdef` functions, the end result might still vary between the two in the compiled extension module. In the following example I checked that the intermediate results in `function1` are all `np.float32` objects. In the generated C of `function2` I checked that there was no cast to `double` (or equivalent typedef). Yet these two functions still produce slightly different results. I'd probably have to dive into the compiled assembly to figure out why, but maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

```
def function1(response, max_loc):    
    tmp = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    tmp[0] = (((response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]) / np.float32(2)) *
             (response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1])))
    tmp[1] = response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]
    tmp[2] = 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))

    print tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]
    return tmp

cpdef function2(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] response, max_loc):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] tmp = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32)
    cdef unsigned int x, y
    x, y = int(max_loc[0]), int(max_loc[1])
    tmp[0] = (((response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]) / <np.float32_t>2) *
             (response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1])))
    tmp[1] = response[y,x+1] - response[y,x-1]
    tmp[2] = 2*(response[y,x] - min(response[y,x-1], response[y,x+1]))

    print tmp[int(0)], tmp[int(1)], tmp[int(2)]
    return tmp
```

Comparison:

```
>>> function1(response, max_loc)
0.0821186 0.314914 1.04306
array([ 0.08211858,  0.31491402,  1.0430603 ], dtype=float32)

>>> function2(response, max_loc)
0.0821186 0.314914 1.04306
array([ 0.08211857,  0.31491402,  1.0430603 ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I actually, after putting the parentheses in the right place(tmp2 is meant to be the numerator, and tmp3 the denominator, so my tmp1 had a pair of parentheses missing),  get the same exact result for function1 and function2.  I see there are quite a few details that are not obvious from the cython documentation. The type(np.float32(1) / 2) == <type 'numpy.float64'> is a bit wicket, one operand is np.float32 object and the other is an int object and the result is neither of them!!

Comment: So, now I can match results, but this means I have to write both my python and cython with this in mind, rather than just do a python version and then get an equivalent cython one. I imagine that in pure python mode I would also have this slight differences problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare:

- `function1` stays `float32_t` all the way through.
- `function2` converts to `float` upon indexing, does the intermediate steps with `float`, then converts back to `float32_t` for the final results.
- `function3` converts to `float`, but then immediately back to `float32_t`, doing the intermediate steps with that.
- `function4` converts to `float`, does the intermediate steps, then returns the final results as `float`.

As for why `function4` prints the same thing as `function2`, but returns something different: If you look at the types, it's simple. The values are apparently close enough that they happen to `print` the same way, but not close enough to `repr` the same way. Which isn't surprising given that they're not the same type.